# How can I add 'text/jsx' type to a script tag via libraries.yml?

Tags: 8, theming

I want to add some react js files to a theme's libraries.yml and I don't know how I can do this in drupal 8.

`<script type="text/babel" src="scripts/example.js"></script>`
or
`<script type="text/jsx" src="scripts/example.js"></script>`

I can't figure it out hot to make the `type="text/jsx"` appear when the file is added to the page.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a wild guess because I couldn't find absolutely nothing. Apparently this works:

```
my-libary:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/node.js: { attributes: {type: text/babel} }
```